# How can I use a controller to click on certain places of my screen?

Tags: mouse, autohotkey, game-controller

I have been playing an online poker game, which I really enjoy. My only complaint is that I have to sit at my PC holding my mouse all the time, which isn't very relaxing for me.

I was wondering if I could somehow use my xbox one controller to control the game. The game only has a couple of buttons you have to press in the bottom right of the screen, so I figured it could be done quite easily.

All I basically have to do is make it so when I press a certain button on my controller it emulates a mouse click on a specific place on my screen, so that it pushes a button in the game. I did some digging online and I think using a program called AutoHotKey would work.

I however don't have any clue on how to write a script that would achieve this, could someone point me in the right direction?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't that cheating? I know  that if you asked this in the Auto-it3 forum, you will get banned very quickly for asking about "game automation". Maybe you know this?

Comment: Writing a script to play a game autonomously might be considered cheating, but writing a script that allows an unusual controller doesn't seem amiss. What difference is there between pushing a mouse button and pushing a controller button that would make the latter action represent cheating?

Comment: If everyone else is using a mouse, and the game is designed that way, then you would maybe have an unfair advantage.

Comment: The OP said the game is poker.  Using a game controller won't give a player any advantages over a mouse user.  You could use google to search for driver software that would allow "use game controller as mouse".  I found this [link](https://gigabytekingdom.com/use-an-xbox-controller-as-a-mouse/) doing that.  You don't need to write a script, just read and follow the instructions.

Comment: @Blaelph, your comment is valid as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use google to search for driver software that would allow "use game controller as mouse". I found this link for [how to use an Xbox Controller as a mouse](https://gigabytekingdom.com/use-an-xbox-controller-as-a-mouse/) doing that. You don't need to write a script, just read and follow the instructions.

Of course, you'll need to connect your controller to your pc with either a USB cable or Bluetooth connection.